# Can't get the view I want : MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some question about create `Mysql` view.

Table:

```
      ID  name  num
      1   ccc    3
      1   bbb    4
      1   aaa    2
```

query:`"SELECT ID,name,num FROM (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY ID,num DESC) AS A GROUP BY ID;"`

Result:

```
       1    bbb 4
```

This result is what I want.

query:

```
"CREATE VIEW I AS SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY ID,num DESC,`name`;
CREATE VIEW T AS SELECT ID,name,num FROM I GROUP BY ID;"
```

VIEW T:

```
       1    aaa 2
```

How can I make VIEW T is same as query result?

Comment: Why it was not used the same query?

Comment: This happen because you are using group by in worng way  .. group by is for aggregation function and not fo get only one row .. (this is not more allowed in mysql 5.6 o sup

Comment: @FieryCat.mysql not support nested query to create view.Create view is to reduce the time for query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to phrase this query is to join to a subquery which finds the maximum number values for each `ID`:

```
CREATE VIEW T AS
SELECT
    t1.ID, t1.name, t1.num
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(num) AS max_num
    FROM test
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID  = t2.ID      AND
       t1.num = t2.max_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Well use the same `select` query in your view statement

```
create view T as
SELECT ID,name,num 
FROM (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY ID,num DESC) AS A 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Finally, you can't create view from a view and thus the below statement is invalid

```
create view T as
select * from I; --I is a view
```